# std::move_if_noexcept calls copy-assignment even though move-assignment is noexcept; why?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm trying to get as close to the *Strong Exception Guarantee* as possible, but when playing around with `std::move_if_noexcept` I ran into some seemingly weird behavior.

Despite the fact that the *move-assignment operator* in the following class is marked `noexcept`, the *copy-assignment operator* is called when invoked with the return value of the function in question.

```
struct A {
  A ()         { /* ... */ }
  A (A const&) { /* ... */ }

  A& operator= (A const&) noexcept { log ("copy-assign"); return *this; }
  A& operator= (A&&)      noexcept { log ("move-assign"); return *this; }

  static void log (char const * msg) {
    std::cerr << msg << "\n";
  }
};
```

```
int main () {
  A x, y;

  x = std::move_if_noexcept (y); // prints "copy-assign"
}
```

---

#### The Question

- Why isn't the *move-assignment operator* called in the previous snippet?

Comment: This question was asked by a student of mine, and hopefully I made the original question justice (even through this extremely boiled down version).

Comment: So this is actually a very interesting subtlety, and I really appreciate the analysis, but I think you left out an interesting example from your answer. You correctly observe that the behavior of `std::move_if_noexcept` appears to depend on move construction rather than assignment, but in the question's prompt, you did not have a move constructor at all, much less a `noexcept` one, due to the special function generation rules. If I add one, then it does indeed print out "move-assign". (See: http://ideone.com/mvPe8b)

Comment: While I'm not too fond of assumptions, I think it's semi-reasonable to assume that if someone bothered to write a `noexcept` move constructor, that their move assignment operator is also `noexcept`. So, I would expect that `std::move_if_noexcept` does the expected thing 99.9% of the time. Of course, I've seen the 0.1% cases in industry before, so, kudos on the find!

Comment: Bonus: An implementation of the "missing" STL function, `move_if_noexcept_assignable`: http://ideone.com/uZOP27. Probably worth a defect report to the committee.

Comment: First steps regarding filing a defect report taken: http://goo.gl/Gj3oex. Sorry for the many back-to-back comments.

Comment: @Mark: The *copy-constructor* qualifies as making the object *MoveConstructible*, and since the declared function isn't marked *noexcept* `is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value == false`; I'll add this to the answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### The Introduction

The name of `move_if_noexcept` certainly implies that the function will yield an *rvalue-reference* as long as this operation is `noexcept`, and with this in mind we soon realize two things:

1. A simple cast from `T&` to `T&&`  or `T const&` can never throw an exception, so what is the purpose of such function?
2. How can `move_if_noexcept` magically deduce the context in which the returned value will be used?

The answer to realization *(2)* is equally scary as natural; `move_if_noexcept` simply can't deduce such context (since it's not a mind-reader), and this in turn means that the function must play by some static set of rules.

---

#### The TL;DR

`move_if_noexcept` will, no matter the context in which it is called, conditionally return an *rvalue-reference* depending on the exception specification of the argument type's *move-**constructor***, and it was only meant to be used when initializing objects (ie. not when assigning to them).

```
template<class T>
void intended_usage () {
  T first;
  T second (std::move_if_noexcept (first));
}
```

A better name could have been `move_if_move_ctor_is_noexcept_or_the_only_option`; though a bit tedious to type, at least it would have expressed the intended usage.

---

#### The Birth Of `move_if_noexcept`

Reading the proposal ([n3050](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3050.html)) that gave birth to `std::move_if_noexcept`, we find the following paragraph (emphasize mine):

> We propose that instead of using `std::move(x)` in those cases, thus granting permission for the compiler to use any available **move constructor**, maintainers of these particular operations should use `std::move_if_noexcept(x)`, which grants permission move unless it could throw and the type is copyable.
>
> Unless `x` is a move-only type, or is known to have a **nonthrowing move constructor**, the operation would fall back to copying `x`, just as though `x` had never acquired a **move constructor** at all.

---

#### So, what is it that `move_if_noexcept` does?

`std::move_if_noexcept` will conditionally cast the passed *lvalue-reference* to an *rvalue-reference*, unless;

- A potential *move-constructor* might throw, and;
- the type is [CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible).

```
// Standard Draft n4140 : [utility]p2

template<class T>
constexpr conditional_t<
  !is_nothrow_move_constructible::value && is_copy_constructible<T>::value,
  const T&, T&&
> move_if_noexcept (T& x) noexcept;
```

This basically means that it will only yield an *rvalue-reference* if it can prove that it is the only viable alternative, or if it is guaranteed not to throw an exception (expressed through `noexcept`).

---

#### The Verdict

`std::move` is an unconditional cast to an *rvalue-reference*, whereas `std::move_if_noexcept` depends on the ways an object can be *move-constructed* - therefore it should only be used in places where we are actuallying constructing objects, not when we are assigning to them.

The *copy-assignment operator* in your snippet is invoked since `move_if_noexcept` can't find a *move-constructor* marked `noexcept`, but since it has a *copy-constructor* the function will yield a type, `A const&`, that is suitable for such.

Please note that a *copy-constructor* qualifies as the type being *MoveConstructible*, this means that we can make `move_if_noexcept` return an *rvalue-reference* through the following adjustment of your snippet:

```
struct A {
  A ()                  { /* ... */ }
  A (A const&) noexcept { /* ... */ }
  
  ...
};
```

---

#### Examples

```
struct A {
  A ();
  A (A const&);
};

A a1;
A a2 (std::move_if_noexcept (a1)); // `A const&` => copy-constructor
```

```
struct B {
  B ();
  B (B const&);
  B (B&&) noexcept;
};

B b1;
B b2 (std::move_if_noexcept (b1)); // `B&&` => move-constructor
                                   //          ^ it's `noexcept`
```

```
struct C {
  C ();
  C (C&&);
};

C c1;
C c2 (std::move_if_noexcept (c1)); // `C&&` => move-constructor
                                   //          ^ the only viable alternative
```

```
struct D {
  C ();
  C (C const&) noexcept;
};

C c1;
C c2 (std::move_if_noexcept (c1)); // C&& => copy-constructor
                                   //        ^ can be invoked with `T&&`
```

---

#### Further reading:

- [**cppreference.com** - MoveConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveConstructible)
- [**cppreference.com** - CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible)
- [**cppreference.com** - std::move_if_noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept)